# Customizing the GraphQL schema of a Gatsby project with nested types breaks functionality of transformer plugins

Tags: graphql, gatsby

In a project where I'm sourcing data from NetlifyCMS I need to extend the GraphQL schema of Gatsby because there are optional fields in my CMS, which would cause errors trying to query non-existing data from GraphQL.

The below code extends the GraphQL types to always include the optional fields

```js
// gatsby-node.js
// ADD OPTIONAL TYPES

// note: I have also tried exports.sourceNodes
exports.createSchemaCustomization = ({ actions }) => {
  const { createTypes } = actions
  const typeDefs = `
    type SettingsJson implements Node {
      tags: String
      name: String
      phone: String
      email: String
      additional_info: [SettingsJsonAdditional_info]
    }

    type SettingsJsonAdditional_info {
      type: String
      text: String
    }
  `
  createTypes(typeDefs)
}
```

Sourcing and transforming the `tags`, `name`, `phone` and `email` work as expected. Queries return `null` if an optional field has not been filled out, and the query returns the correct value after being set. However, querying for `additional_info` *always* returns `null` even when containing data.

This is the json-file generated by NetlifyCMS:

```json
{
  "name": "Name Nameson",
  "phone": "+41 1234 5678",
  "email": "mail@example.com",
  "additional-info": [
    {
      "type": "Booking",
      "text": "Booker McBookerson <book@book.com>"
    }
  ]
}
```

The following GraphQL query shows that the data is not being transformed properly when extending the GraphQL schema myself.

**Query**

```
query {
  file(relativePath: {eq: "settings/contacts.json"}) {
    internal {
      content
    }
    
    childSettingsJson {
      name
      phone
      email
      additional_info {
        type
        text
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Response**

```json
{
  "data": {
    "file": {
      "internal": {
        "content": "{\n  \"name\": \"Name Nameson\",\n  \"phone\": \"+41 1234 5678\",\n  \"email\": \"mail@example.com\",\n  \"additional-info\": [\n    {\n      \"type\": \"Booking\",\n      \"text\": \"Booker McBookerson <book@book.com>\"\n    },\n    {\n      \"type\": \"Booking2\",\n      \"text\": \"Booker2 McBookerson <book@book.com>\"\n    }\n  ]\n}"
      },
      "childSettingsJson": {
        "name": "Name Nameson",
        "phone": "+41 1234 5678",
        "email": "mail@example.com",
        "additional_info": null
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {}
}
```

When the types are inferred by the transformer plugin itself I get the expected data when querying

```json
// ...
        "additional_info": [
          {
            "type": "Booking",
            "text": "Booker McBookerson <book@book.com>"
          }
        ]
// ...
```

This example uses `json` files with `gatsby-transformer-json`. I have tried with `gatsby-transformer-yaml` too with the same results.

Is it possible to add my array of `SettingsJsonAdditional_info` to the schema to get the "optional field" functionality I'm looking for?

Answer (score 0):

One kind of hacky solution I have found is to make the transformer plugin infer the types by adding a dummy-file that will be sourced and transformed along with "real" files.

```json
// dummy.json
{
    "name": "dummy",
    "phone": "dummy",
    "email": "dummy",
    "tags": "dummy",
    "additional-info": [
      {
        "type": "dummy",
        "text": "dummy"
      }
    ]
  }
```

This file can be hidden from NetlifyCMS (by simply not including a UI entry for it in the `config.yml` file of NetlifyCMS. It will guarantee that you can always query for the fields included in this file without getting GraphQL "field doesn't exist" errors.